# How Can replicate this cryptojs encrypt with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

I have this encrypt function in Typescript.

```
encrypt( text, password) {
let response = '';
let text= btoa(text);

const keyBytes = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, this.KEY_COMPLEMENTARY, { keySize: 48 / 4, iterations: 1000 });
const key = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words, 32);
const iV = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(keyBytes.words.splice(32 / 4), 16);
const data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse(text);
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, { iv: iV });

response = encrypted.toString();

return response;}
```

Is it possible to program this encryption in PHP?

Comment: It probably is, but a common security rule is: don't create your own crypto functions. Rely on the available functions. Why would you need the exact same function? To decrypt? Encrypt in JavaScript, decrypt on PHP?

Comment: The JavaScript code uses PBKDF2 to derive key and IV from a password, and applies both for encryption with AES. In PHP, e.g. `hash_pbkdf2` and `openssl_encrypt` can be used.